# git automatically ignore commits by file

Tags: git, git-blame

I'm using the following command for git to ignore commits listed in `.git-blame-ignore-revs`

> git config blame.ignoreRevsFile .git-blame-ignore-revs

This file is tracked in a remote git repo. Every developer has to set up this command manually on first pull. I have no idea why would the file not be seen automatically like .gitignore is for example.

Is there a way to make git automatically ignore commits accroding to `.git-blame-ignore-revs`?

Comment: You can use `git config --global` to set it once for all your repositories. Still needs to be done once though

Comment: git config happens on you rmachine, you cannot sync config through the repository. Every developer has to set this up on their own. What you could do, is provide a `setup.sh` script that your developers have to run when (first) checking out the code, but there is not way to set it up automatically.

Comment: Does `.gitattributes ` have such a option to do so?

Comment: @cacojr no, `.gitattributes` does not set any `git config` options